# SQL get the Nth row, after deleting keep getting the same row

Tags: sql, rowid

I was asked how to get the Nth row from a table. But, with the additional requirement says even after deletion/insertion of rows, it should keep return the same row.

I was suspecting that there is a way to do that.

But, if you get any idea please let me know. Thanks ahead.

Comment: Can you show an example?

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as the "nth" row of a table.  SQL tables represent unordered sets.  They don't have a particular order, *unless* a column specifies the ordering.  If you have an auto-incrementing column (also called "sequence" or "identity") or a column with a default creation date, then you can use that.  As in:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, row_number() over (order by id) as seqnum
      from table t
     ) t
where t = @NTH;
```

You have this tagged "rowid", but not a database.  You can use rowid in Oracle and SQLite (and perhaps in other databases).  This doesn't necessarily guarantee a particular ordering however.

Comment: First, thanks for your response. And I agree on the point that there is no particular order unless used order by. But, I guess the point is whether there is a way to get the nth row after deletion and insertion happened.